# How do I find out which remote desktop sessions are active?

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

How do I find out which remote desktop sessions are active on a Windows Server 2003 box?

Comment: Here's the same question for Windows Server 2012, in which Terminal Services Manager is no longer available: http://serverfault.com/questions/471224/how-do-i-access-the-list-of-currently-logged-on-users-through-terminal-services/.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Start -> Administrative tools -> **Terminal Services Manager**

Click on your servers name and it will list the active sessions on the right, there is also a field for the session state. Another tab called 'Sessions' will show active users, listeners and the console sessions.

Answer (score 30):

The commandline way, which you can even remotely use, is

```
qwinsta /SERVER:{servername}
```

which will list the current sessions and their status, and with

```
rwinsta /SERVER:{servername} {sessionid}
```

and the proper privileges you can disconnect a session, particularly useful when the limit has been reached and you are not connected.

{sessionid} is the ID number listed in qwinsta's result

Comment: I get "qwinsta : No session exists for *" but running "query user" on the server directly clearly shows two sessions.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a remote desktop open to the server in question, you can see other sessions on the same server in the Task Manager (`Ctrl-Shift-Esc`).

Comment: Yes and the good thing, is that you can even disconnect or logged them out (if you're admin).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer who was unable to RDP to a server because all available sessions were in use.  I don't have Terminal Services manager, so none of the answers above applied.  I use powershell for this kind of Windows service management, and I had success using the PowerShell module [PSTerminalServices](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PSTerminalServices/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5479), which is from a MS employee (or group).  Hit the link to install the MSI, then run the following from PowerShell:

```
Import-Module PSTerminalServices
Get-TSSession -ComputerName _MyRDPServer_ | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Task Manager you can click on the Users Tab to see which sessions are running. Right-click on a User to disconnect or logoff.