# How do I access the list of currently logged on users through Terminal Services Manager in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, user-management, user-permissions, windows-terminal-services

In Windows 2003 and 2008 we had Terminal Services Manager (see screenshot below). However in Windows server 2012 it's [gone](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/winserver8gen/thread/1e283abc-a0d5-480c-8fca-814bf912bddf).

Does anyone know how to access the list of currently remotely logged on users in Windows 2012 through a similar tool or some other way?

[image]

(I tried connecting to Windows 2012 from Windows 2008, that's why you see "win2012" in the TSM groups list. But that didn't quite work, and that's not a solution to my problem either. I was just trying to somehow manage remote users on the Win 2012 server.)

Comment: have you run query session from CMD or PS shell? from there you should be able to run kill session on the session id in question.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for the link to the other question.  I had searched, but hadn't found that question.  Cole's answer below also contains information that's not in the answers to the other question.

Comment: Not sure about 2012, but in 2012 R2 you can view and manage current connections in Server Manager. Remote Desktop Services > Collections > [CollectionName].

Answer (score 50):

You can use `qwinsta` from the command line to display the current RDP sessions.

```
 qwinsta /server:computer01

 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 console                                     0  Conn    wdcon
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen  rdpwd
                   administrator             2  Disc    rdpwd
```

To kill a session use `rwinsta` to delete the session specifying the ID number:

`rwinsta /server:computer01 3`

[Here's the list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771505.aspx) of command line tools for Remote Desktop.

Or, you can use PowerShell:

`Get-RDUserSession` and `Disconnect-RDUser`

[Here's the list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj215451.aspx) of those cmdlets.

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  I think I prefer the more verbose commands `query user` and `reset session` as those are easier for me to remember than `rwinsta`.

Comment: Very nice. Defaults to local machine, so just **qwinsta** then **rwinsta 3**, faster than trying to find tsadmin

Answer (score 31):

Yep, tsadmin is gone. Kinda' sucks.  There's RDMS through Server Manager and the Remote Desktop Powershell cmdlets (`get-command *RD*`), but those both require that a full Remote Desktop Services deployment exist on that server.  Those don't work on servers without RDS deployments or on workstations.

You can use Task Manager... or, if you want something command-line, you could use this utility that I wrote specifically for this: [users.exe](http://www.myotherpcisacloud.com/post/2013/01/16/Usersexe-v1003.aspx)

Oh and there's also quser.exe that Microsoft already wrote, but my utility does a little extra that quser doesn't do.

Comment: C:\>logoff.exe x      Where x is the session ID

Comment: @RyanRies, What about the terminal services configuration `tscc.msc`? What's the equivalent in Server 2012?

Comment: @Pacerier Gone. Sucks, huh? You can still use the MMC snap-ins you know and love, remotely, from a 2008 R2 server against a 2012 server. You can also just directly modify the registry keys, or use Group Policy. Microsoft went on this weird VDI kick with 2012, and they left a serious gap by dropping the legacy RDSH administration tools.

Answer (score 13):

Just open the Users tab in Task Manager.  You'll get a full list of user sessions, their states, and running processes.  Also you can log them off through the right-click menu.

It seems this is the replacement for tsadmin

Comment: I was just about to add this as the answer. Simple, quick and exactly what is needed to see who is logged in, and log them off if necessary.

Answer (score 8):

I've just discovered that most of the actions can be performed from TaskManager, right on users (logoff, send messages etc...)

Comment: Can you access a list of currently logged on users though?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to the tsadmin problem. Copy these files from a 2008 server to the Windows 2012/8 computer under c:\windows\system32

- tsadmin.dll
- tsadmin.msc
- umcRes.dll
- wts.dll

Then import these registry settings and you have Tsadmin.msc working again! :)

Reg file is attached.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\FX:{3FCE72B6-A31B-43ac-ADDA-120E1E56EB0F}]
"ApplicationBase"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,\
  73,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,00,00
"About"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"VersionStringIndirect"="@C:\\Windows\\System32\\umcRes.dll,-106"
"ProviderStringIndirect"=hex(2):40,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,\
  00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,\
  5c,00,75,00,6d,00,63,00,52,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,\
  00,31,00,30,00,32,00,00,00
"NameString"="Remote Desktop Services Manager"
"HelpTopic"=hex(2):25,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,72,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,70,00,5c,00,74,00,73,00,5f,00,6d,00,61,\
  00,6e,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,63,00,68,00,6d,00,00,00
"AssemblyName"="tsadmin"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50215"
"Description"="Manage Remote Desktop Services sessions"
"DescriptionStringIndirect"=hex(2):40,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,\
  64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,\
  00,5c,00,75,00,6d,00,63,00,52,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,\
  2d,00,31,00,30,00,34,00,00,00
"LinkedHelpTopics"=hex(2):25,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,72,00,6f,\
  00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,70,00,5c,00,74,00,73,00,5f,00,\
  6d,00,61,00,6e,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,63,00,68,00,6d,00,00,00
"NameStringIndirect"=hex(2):40,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,\
  00,77,00,73,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,\
  75,00,6d,00,63,00,52,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,31,\
  00,30,00,33,00,00,00
"IconIndirect"=hex(2):40,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,\
  00,73,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,75,00,\
  6d,00,63,00,52,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,31,00,31,\
  00,31,00,00,00
"FxVersion"="2.0.1.7"
"Type"="Microsoft.TerminalServices.Monitor.SnapIn.TSManagerSnapIn, tsadmin, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
"FolderBitmapsColorMask"=dword:00000000
"ModuleName"="tsadmin.dll"
"Provider"="Microsoft Corporation"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\FX:{3FCE72B6-A31B-43ac-ADDA-120E1E56EB0F}\NodeTypes]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\FX:{3FCE72B6-A31B-43ac-ADDA-120E1E56EB0F}\Standalone]
```

Answer (score -1):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2202.remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-client-and-windows-server-dsforum2wiki.aspx

> Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) enables IT administrators to
>   remotely manage roles and features in Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows
>   Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2 from a
>   computer that is running Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows Vista, or
>   Windows 7.
>
> If you need to install management tools in Windows Server 2008,
>   Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, or Windows Server 2012 R2
>   for specific roles or features running on remote servers, there's no
>   need to install additional software. Open the Add Features Wizard in
>   Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2, or the Add Roles and
>   Features Wizard in Windows Server 2012 and later releases, and on the
>   Select Features page, expand Remote Server Administration Tools and
>   select the tools that you want to install.

The linked article also lists RSAT download links for all windows versions since Vista.
Though the size is huge (about 240 Mb for Win7).

I was able to install it on Windows 7.

After that `tsadmin.msc` works as expected.

Comment: As far as I can tell from reading <http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/10/30/windows-8-windows-server-2012-remote-desktop-management-server.aspx>, installation of RSAT/RDMS on Server 2012 R2 appears to only be available when using "Remote Desktop Services installation" as the Installation Type. It doesn't appear for me when using "Role-based or feature-based installation". Unfortunately, I don't know enough about RDS deployment in 2012 to know if that's what I want to do. It also requires that the server be joined to a domain. I just want tsadmin back!