# How to programmatically logout idle users on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

I've searched a lot but couldn't find a direct solution. Can anyone tell me how to logoff idle users from a remote desktop connection to a Windows Server 2012 server after a period of time?  These are Windows 7 clients.

Comment: [Related thread](http://serverfault.com/q/471224/118258).

Answer (score 2):

[Since you want to do it by GPO, the answer is the same for Server 2012 as for older Windows Server OSes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx).

The Group Policy settings you're interested in are located at:

```
Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Session Time Limits

User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Session Time Limits
```

You are specifically looking for the setting named `Set time limit for active but idle Remote Desktop Services sessions`

[image]